# Mongodb groupby and lookup/join

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections, with following structure and data

**Trx collection**

```
id  | trxid | subitem | clazz
1   | 100   | 1       | A
2   | 100   | 2       | A
3   | 100   | 3       | B
4   | 200   | 1       | B
```

**Class collection**

```
id | clazz | applicable
1  | A     | y
2  | B     | n
```

I am looking for an output grouping by trxid, along with count of sub item and count of applicable and non-applicable sub items. For example, for the data above output

```
trxid | subitem count | applicable sub items count | non-applicable sub items count
100   | 3             | 2                          | 1
200   | 1             | 0                          | 1
```

I have got the sub items count working. I looked at "$lookup" but not sure how to map this count by applicable and non-applicable subitems count like above. Any pointers to above is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

There are 8000+ documents in collection, but following query returns only a subset.

```
db.trx.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : "$trxid", count: { $sum : 1 } } } ])

[
  { _id: 'Trx100', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'Trx101', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'Trx102', count: 6 },
  { _id: 'Trx103', count: 5 },
  { _id: 'Trx104', count: 2 },
  { _id: 'Trx105', count: 2 },
  { _id: 'Trx106', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'Trx107', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'Trx108', count: 7 },
  { _id: 'Trx109', count: 26 },
  { _id: 'Trx110', count: 18 },
  { _id: 'Trx111', count: 5 },
  { _id: 'Trx112', count: 15 },
  { _id: 'Trx113', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'Trx114', count: 8 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pipeline method to get the groups you want.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/3NfMUJrXVbS

```
db.trx.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        clazz: "$clazz",
        trxid: "$trxid"
      },
      total: {$sum: 1},
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "classes",
      as: "clazz",
      let: {clazzName: "$_id.clazz"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
          $expr: {$eq: ["$$clazzName", "$clazz"]}
        }},
        {$project: {
            applicable: {$eq: ["$applicable", "y"]}
        }}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.trxid",
      subitemCount: {$sum: "$total"},
      applicableCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {$eq: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$clazz.applicable", 0]}, true]},
            '$total',
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      nonApplicableCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {$eq: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$clazz.applicable", 0]}, false]},
            '$total',
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you GitGitBoom, with a minor modification of my use case it is done. It has been very helpful on right time.